# How to use memcpy correctly with different types of arrays

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a templated class named `Stack` that has a private method `resize`.

Whenever I use the `int` or `double` template version of this class, it works as desired. But, whenever I use the `float` or `string` versions of the template, it crashes. I believe that it's a problem with my `memcpy` function call. How am I supposed to use it correctly?

```
template <class Type>

void Stack<Type>::resize(int capacity) {
    if(capacity >= MAX_SIZE)
        capacity = MAX_SIZE;

    Type* copy = new Type[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        copy[i] = s[i];
    }

    s = new Type[capacity];

    memcpy(s, copy, sizeof(Type) * capacity);

    size = capacity;

    delete copy;
}
```

`s` is a heap allocated member variable array of type `Type`.

Comment: Why don't you just do -- `delete s; s = copy;` -- Instead of allocating another array, copying *again* and deleting the first copy?

Comment: don't use `memcpy` in C++, use [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: *Especially* without checking that the type is a POD.

Comment: What is `N`? Are you sure it crashes at `memcpy()`?

Comment: Assuming that `s` points to the actual data in your stack then you got a memory leak. You copy it over into `copy` and then you point `s` to a new array without deleting the old.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I tried that. It now crashes even with the `int` and `double` templates.

Comment: @timrau `N` is an `int` member variable that counts the current index.

Comment: Then you must make sure that `N` is always less than or equal to `capacity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is incorrect to use `memcpy` to copy non-POD types.  Just use a for loop, or `std::copy`.

Second, you are doing more work than necessary (and you have a memory leak).

```
void Stack<Type>::resize(int capacity) {
    if(capacity >= MAX_SIZE)
        capacity = MAX_SIZE;

    Type* copy = new Type[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        copy[i] = s[i];
    }
```

Up to this point, you're okay. You've allocated a new array, and assigned over the elements from the old array. I'm assuming `N` is the number of valid elements.

```
s = new Type[capacity];
```

Assuming that `s` previously pointed to an allocated array, this is a memory leak. First, you need to delete the previous data.

```
delete [] s;
```

Then, you don't need to allocate another array. Use the one you just allocated.

```
s = copy;
```

All together, the function now looks like this:

```
template <class Type>
void Stack<Type>::resize(int capacity) {
    if(capacity >= MAX_SIZE)
        capacity = MAX_SIZE;

    Type* copy = new Type[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        copy[i] = s[i];
    }

    delete [] s;
    s = copy;
    size = capacity;
}
```

If there are still problems, some other part of your code is broken.

Comment: This code is only taking into account when the new `capacity` is **greater than** the current capacity, but not if the new `capacity` is **equal to or less than** the current capacity.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: True. I am (perhaps incorrectly) assuming that he is not calling the function passing a smaller size than it currently has.  I don't know under what circumstances this function is called. But I presume that it is something that should probably be checked in the function, as you are implying.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I am, in fact, calling this also when `capacity` is **less than** the current capacity. How does this code not work in that circumstance? I can't recognize why.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class Type>
void Stack<Type>::resize(int capacity)
{
    if (capacity > MAX_SIZE)
        capacity = MAX_SIZE;
    else if (capacity < 0)
        capacity = 0;

    if (capacity == size)
        return;

    Type* new_s = new Type[capacity];
    std::copy(s, s + std::min(size, capacity), new_s);   
    delete[] s;
    s = new_s;
    size = capacity;

    if (N >= size)
        N = size-1;
}
```

Or, you could simply make your `Stack` use a `std::vector` instead of a raw array, and then you do not have to worry about these details anymore:

```
template <class Type>
class Stack
{
private:
    std::vector<Type> s;
    int N;
public:
    void resize(int capacity);
};

template <class Type>
void Stack<Type>::resize(int capacity)
{
    s.resize(capacity);
    if (N >= s.size())
        N = s.size()-1;
}
```

Comment: Definitely better to use `std::vector` (or just `std::stack`), since your version leaks memory if `T`'s copy constructor throws an exception...