# Why does this array resizing code only work when increasing, not decreasing?

Tags: c++

I have a `Stack` implementation that I'm making in C++. In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340473/how-to-use-memcpy-correctly-with-different-types-of-arrays), somebody said that this function, `resize()`, only works if `capacity` is greater than `size`. I tested it and it's true. The program crashes if `capacity` is less than or equal to `size`.

I can't seem to realize what is causing it to crash. Could somebody shine some light on this?

```
template <class Type>

void Stack<Type>::resize(int capacity) {
    if(capacity > MAX_SIZE)
        capacity = MAX_SIZE;

    Type* copy = new Type[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        copy[i] = s[i];
    }

    delete [] s;
    s = copy;
    size = capacity;
}
```

- `s` is a `Type *` array.
- `N` is an `int` member variable that counts the next open index.
- `size` is an `int` member variable that keeps track of the array size.

Comment: what is N in the code?

Comment: `N` is an `int` member variable that counts the next open index.

Comment: Because if `capacity` is smaller than size, you will be going out of bounds in the loop (assuming `N` is `size`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `N` is the size of `s` (or is otherwise somehow related to it) and `N` is greater than `capacity, this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    copy[i] = s[i];
}
```

writes into memory beyond the end of `copy`. Writing beyond the end of an array is an error.